# CouchDB local.ini log setting getting overwritten

Tags: couchdb

We have CouchDB 1.5.0 installed and running successfully on a Windows 2008 server. Everything has been working fine for several months, but lately it's started crashing with little information in the logs.

I found `local.ini` and changed the `[log]` setting from `error` to `debug`, then restarted the service. Everything seemed to work fine, except the setting in `local.ini` automatically reverted back to `error`. I downloaded and ran Process Monitor and determined that `erl.exe` is the guilty party for updating the `.ini` file.

I even tried removing the `[log]` block entirely from `local.ini` to try to grab the default value. When I do this, the `erl.exe` process comes back through and adds back the `[log]` block, with the log level set to `error`.

Am I missing something? Obviously the purpose of `local.ini` is to override default values. I've seen nothing that indicates why some settings, like the log level, cannot be changed. Process Monitor tells me that the only `.ini` files being accessed are `default.ini` and `local.ini`, so I think I can rule out an extraneous `.ini` file somewhere that's mucking up the settings.

I'm really at a loss for how to debug our crash if I can't even get more logging info out of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using Configuration page in Futon? It should do the right thing™.